# Flowplayer flash component plays sound but not video

Tags: flash, flv, flowplayer

Okay, I've been researching this all day and it's driving me nuts. The flow player will play the audio of a *.flv, but doesn't play the video and I've no idea why. The initial example page using the default flowplayer flv url works fine. When I change the url to my godaddy site, it doesn't work.

I've searched Stackoverflow, googled, and, of course, looked in the forums at the Flowplayer website. I found some articles talking about the flash file missing it's meta data and that throwing the flowplayer off. I'm using Movavi Video Suite 8 to perform the conversion to flash from mp4. I think the metadata is included in the flash file when it converts, but I'm not certain. I used the meta data injector found here: http://www.buraks.com/flvmdi/ to inject meta data into the flash files and it still did not work.

Also of note is that the player's progress bar shows the start, current, & end time values of the video, so I think the metadata is there. I've still no clue why this isn't working, though.

I wonder if it's my *.flv file as the player will load the mp4 file it was generated from. I used a premium application called MOVAVI Video Suite to perform the conversion. I don't think this is the case because I can upload the converted *.flv file to youtube and it plays fine.

Also worth noting is that the Flow Player plays audio and not video both when the flv source is pointed to my godaddy site as well as when its pointed to a local folder on my hard drive that contains the player, it's files, the video files, and the example .html page being used to test this.

Possibly something else worth mentioning is that I have not put the flow player files on my godaddy site yet because the video picture isn't showing locally.

I have the same issue with the LongTailVideo player.

Here is the html for my test page:

```
<!-- 
    include flowplayer JavaScript file that does  
    Flash embedding and provides the Flowplayer API.
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer-3.1.4.min.js"></script>

<!-- some minimal styling, can be removed -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- page title -->
<title>Minimal Flowplayer setup</title>
```

```
<div id="page">

    <h1>Minimal Flowplayer setup</h1>

    <p>View commented source code to get familiar with Flowplayer installation.</p>

    <!-- this A tag is where your Flowplayer will be placed. it can be anywhere -->
    <a  
         href="http://www.thebaisenzone.com/rememberthejourney/example/VID00003.flv"  
         style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px"  
         id="player"> 
    </a> 

    <!--<a  
         href="file:///C:/Development/MVC/flowplayer/example/VID00003.flv"  
         style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px"  
         id="player"> 
    </a>    --> 

    <!-- this will install flowplayer inside previous A- tag. -->
    <script>
        flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.1.5.swf");
    </script>



    <!-- 
        after this line is purely informational stuff. 
        does not affect on Flowplayer functionality 
    -->

    <p>     
        If you are running these examples <strong>locally</strong> and not on some webserver you must edit your 
        <a href="http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html">
            Flash security settings</a>. 
    </p>

    <p class="less">
        Select "Edit locations" &gt; "Add location" &gt; "Browse for files" and select
        flowplayer-x.x.x.swf you just downloaded.
    </p>


    <h2>Documentation</h2>

    <p>
        <a href="http://flowplayer.org/documentation/installation/index.html">Flowplayer installation</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <a href="http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/index.html">Flowplayer configuration</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        See this identical page on <a href="http://flowplayer.org/demos/example/index.htm">Flowplayer website</a> 
    </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue.
my flowplayer generates in page body something like this

```
<a href="../resimler/video/test.flv" class="flowplayer">
  <object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../mult/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" id="fp_43298124_api">
    <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
    <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
    <param value="high" name="quality">
    <param value="false" name="cachebusting">
    <param value="#000000" name="bgcolor"><param value="config={&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;fp_43298124&quot;,&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;../resimler/video/test.flv&quot;},&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;../resimler/video/test.flv&quot;}]}" name="flashvars">
  </object>
</a>
```

when i put `style="width:200px;height:200px"` to `<object>` tag, i could be able to see video.
may be it help someones

Comment: When I put two videos in a row, they all dispears, do you know why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same issue and maybe this might help someone. I found by putting a width and height on the container of the player the video showed up.

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
    <a href="" .... flowplayer call
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your file compatible with flash?  I mean is the audio & video codecs supported by the Adobe Flash runtime?  [List of codecs supported by Adobe Flash Player](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html)  That might be causing the error.

As another means you could try a different encoding application, [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) is pretty good and very easy to use, based on FFmpeg.  In the main WinFF window click *Convert To* -> Websites Device *Preset* -> Flash Video for Web